# Non probabilistic algorithm for min-cut problem?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, branch-cuts, probabilistic-method

I know about Karger's algorithm and its variations, all of them being probabilistic. Is there non-trivial (i.e. non-brutefoce) deterministic algorithm for mincut problem?

Comment: Do you know what is a flow in a graph?

Comment: @FPE I think I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to solve this problem is to use the following. Let $c(S|T)$ be the cost of a cut (i.e. the total weight of the edges going from $S$ to $T$, and let $c(f)$ be the value of a flow going from $s$ to $t$.

**Theorem:** Let $G$ be a connected graph, and let $s,t$ be vertices of $G$. Then
$$\min_{(S,T) \text{ cut}}  c(S|T) = \max_{f \text{ flow from $s$ to $t$}} c(f).$$

Thus, finding a cut of minimum cost amounts to finding a flow of maximum value. The latter problem can be solved by a lot of deterministic algorithms. I would say that the Ford-Fulkerson and Edmonds-Karp algorithms are the more common.

If you want to know why the theorem above holds, you can express the min-cut problem as a linear program and use the duality theorem of linear programming.

Comment: Karger's algorithm is for finding the smallest cardinality cutset on a graph, not just the smallest capacity cut that separates given vertices $S$ and $T$. Of course you can solve $O(|V|)$ max flow problems to solve the min cut problem.

Comment: @wonko not sure I follow, could you explain the difference?

Comment: Think of it this way. The general min-cut problem can be solved by solving a minimum $s$-$t$ cut problem for each possible $(s,t)$ pair on the graph.

Answer (score 2):

Just solved the problem deterministically in near-linear time..

http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5123